# What software supported the Mockingboard on the Apple II?

Tags: apple-ii, hardware

Is there a list somewhere? Might be nice to compile a list here.

I'm assuming mostly games but also music and educational software made use of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Apple Vault](http://www.applevault.com) has a fairly comprehensive [list of software titles which supported the Mockingboard](http://www.applevault.com/hardware/sweet_micro_systems/mockingboard/).

I do see several music programs in the list:

```
Bank Street Music Writer
Clarinet Master
Flute Master
GuitarMaster
Music Construction Set
Music Star
Saxophone Master
Trumpet Master
```

And of course the list of games is quite long:

```
Adventure Construction Set
Airsim-3
Apple Cider Spider
At the Gates of Moscow 1941
Auto Gyro
Battle Cruiser SMS-2000
BerZap!
Bouncing Kamungas
Broadside
Crime Wave
Crowther and Woods Adventure
Crypt of Medea
GI-Joe
Lady Tut
Lancaster
Legionnaire
Lethal Labyrinth
Maze Craze
Microbe
Night Flight
One on One
Operation: Obliteration
Pitfall II
Popeye
Rescue Raiders
Silent Service
Singing Master
Skyfox
Spy Strikes Back
Tactical Armor Command
Thunderbombs
Ultima III
Ultima IV
Ultima V
Under Fire
Willy Byte
Window
Zaxxon
ZooKeeper
```

Although based on [this Atari Age discussion thread](http://atariage.com/forums/topic/228710-games-with-mockingboard-support/), some of these titles work better than others, and some of them (G.I. Joe, Lancaster) not at all.

In 2005 ReactiveMicro.com re-introduced the Mockingboard.  Their [manual can be found here](http://www.downloads.reactivemicro.com/Public/Apple%20II%20Items/Hardware/Mockingboard_v1/Mockingboard-v1a-Docs.pdf), and has a similar list of supported titles.